# JQuery UI AutoComplete, How can select & highlight first autocomplete result by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

HI we are using **jquery ui autocomplete** method to show keywords on my home page search.we want to set some default functionality for this like the **first autocomplete keyword**(result) should be **automatically highlighted & select** .It will help us when somebody just start a word & not select any populated result and press enter that time first autocomplete keyword will select by default.

We are using this code for autocomplete

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

function monkeyPatchAutocomplete() {

```
jQuery.ui.autocomplete.prototype._renderItem = function( ul, item) {

    var re = new RegExp("(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" + this.term + ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi");
    var t = item.label.replace(re,"<span style='font-weight:bold;color:#434343;'>" + 
            "$&" + 
            "</span>");
    return jQuery( "<li></li>" )
        .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
        .append( "<a>" + t + "</a>" )
        .appendTo( ul );
};
```

}

function getKeywords(){

```
    var allKeywords = <?php echo json_encode($allKeywords); ?>;

    return allKeywords;
}

var URL = '<?php e(SITE_URL); ?>fronts/search';

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

monkeyPatchAutocomplete();

var username = jQuery('#username');

username.autocomplete({
minLength    : 1,
source        : URL


});

var CityKeyword = jQuery('#CityKeyword');

CityKeyword.autocomplete({
minLength    : 1,
source        : getKeywords()
});

});

// A custom jQuery method for placeholder text:

jQuery.fn.defaultText = function(value){

var element = this.eq(0);
element.data('defaultText',value);

element.focus(function(){
if(element.val() == value){
element.val('').removeClass('defaultText');
}
}).blur(function(){
if(element.val() == '' || element.val() == value){
    element.addClass('defaultText').val(value);
}
});

return element.blur();
}
```

I also tried `autofocous: true` & `selectFirst: true`  in this way but not solved my problem

```
var username = jQuery('#username');

username.autocomplete({
minLength    : 1,
   autoFocus: true,
source        : URL,
   selectFirst: true

});
```